# Declaring noise vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying a code in MATLAB and finding difficulty in declaring noise vectors like

```
n ∼ N(0,Rn) and w ∼ N(0,Rw)
```

and

```
Relay matrix A ∈ R( M×N)
A = diag[√@i √hi ]     i=1,2...,M
```

Can anyone please help me declaring this in MATLAB?
 where `hi` is channel gain and `@i` is amplifier coefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a vector of normally distributed random samples by

```
randn(n,1)
```

See http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html

You can create a diagonal matrix with

```
diag(v)
```

where `v` is the vector of diagonal entries. See http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html

Comment: thanks a lot for the help cfh,how the values can be chosen for channel gain and amplifier coefficient?